Python 3: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
This question has been asked here a few times and I've read and tried most of the answers, but I'm no closer to the solution.
When I enter the URL manually in a browser (I have tried Firefox, Edge and Opera) everything works fine.
As soon as I start my script, I get a: "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden"
Originally I had not set a header in the request, but now the header is in and I still get a 403.
Line: "with urllib.request.urlopen(f"{MP_URL}/api/assets/asset/{el['id']}") as f:"
Code:
import json
import os
import urllib.request

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla 5.0')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

MP_URL = "https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace"
JSON_DIR = "./data"
OUT_FILE = "mp_vault_list.md"


def main():
    mp_jsons = []
    cost = 0.
    disc = 0.
    currency = ""
    count = 0
    for f in os.listdir(JSON_DIR):
        if not f.endswith(".json"):
            continue
        with open(os.path.join(JSON_DIR, f), encoding="utf8") as fd:
            j = json.load(fd)
            count += len(j['data']['elements'])
            mp_jsons.append(j)
    with open(OUT_FILE, "w+", encoding="utf8") as fd:
        fd.write(f"# Vault content\n\n")
        i = 0
        for j in mp_jsons:
            for el in j['data']['elements']:
                i += 1
                print(f"\rProcessing Vault {i}/{count}", end="")
                # The ID found in the json dump is completely valid, and we have to resolve it to the urlSlug if we
                # want a nice and valid URL
                with urllib.request.urlopen(f"{MP_URL}/api/assets/asset/{el['id']}") as f:
                    jj = json.load(f)
                    jjd = jj['data']['data']
                    fd.write(f"* [{jjd['title']}]({MP_URL}/en-US/product/{jjd['urlSlug']})\n")
                    cost += jjd['priceValue']
                    currency = jjd['currencyCode']
                    try:
                        disc += jjd['discountPriceValue']
                    except KeyError:
                        pass

        fd.write(f"\n# Vault stats\n\n")
        fd.write(f"* Value: {cost / 100}{currency}\n")
        fd.write(f"* Current cost: {disc / 100}{currency}\n")
        fd.write(f"* Size: {count}\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Originally I had not set a header in the request, but now the header is in and I still get a 403.
JSON file in folder data:
{
  "status": "OK",
  "data": {
    "elements": [
      {
        "catalogItemId": "c1889d04a19f42cd86341de462bdd64b",
        "namespace": "ue",
        "categories": null,
        "title": "Tappy Chicken",
        "description": "Tappy Chicken demonstrates how to create a 16-bit-style side-scrolling game using Blueprint!",
        "seller": {
          "id": "o-aa83a0a9bc45e98c80c1b1c9d92e9e",
          "noAi": false,
          "owner": "311cffd7000046919e47765426990332",
          "status": "ACTIVE",
          "accepted": [
            {
              "ns": "ue",
              "custom": false
            }
          ],
          "financeCheckExempted": true,
          "name": "Epic Games",
          "supportEmail": "marketplace-support@unrealengine.com"
        },
        "keyImages": [
          {
            "type": "Thumbnail",
            "url": "https://cdn1.epicgames.com/ue/item/store_TappyChicken_thumbnail-140x140-5f29f37cd10f728c6aaef67b811f2085.png",
            "md5": "5f29f37cd10f728c6aaef67b811f2085",
            "width": 140,
            "height": 140,
            "size": 18856,
            "uploadedDate": "2014-07-31T20:00:16.640Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "Screenshot",
            "url": "https://cdn1.epicgames.com/ue/item/store_TappyChicken_screenshot_3-1920x1080-0315ae3bfe61ea5a124dca24274620fc.png",
            "md5": "0315ae3bfe61ea5a124dca24274620fc",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 1080,
            "size": 225338,
            "uploadedDate": "2014-07-31T20:00:33.092Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "Screenshot",
            "url": "https://cdn1.epicgames.com/ue/item/store_TappyChicken_screenshot_1-1920x1080-797505e1581ee9a86a55b3a88b40c28c.png",
            "md5": "797505e1581ee9a86a55b3a88b40c28c",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 1080,
            "size": 131210,
            "uploadedDate": "2014-07-31T20:00:23.384Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "Featured",
            "url": "https://cdn1.epicgames.com/ue/item/store_TappyChicken_featured-476x246-0ff729b32eac8911749b350a02c26178.png",
            "md5": "0ff729b32eac8911749b350a02c26178",
            "width": 476,
            "height": 246,
            "size": 30643,
            "uploadedDate": "2014-07-31T20:00:05.976Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "Screenshot",
            "url": "https://cdn1.epicgames.com/ue/item/store_TappyChicken_screenshot_2-1920x1080-191ad0f829e90e1884bae1dad4fa5bcd.png",
            "md5": "191ad0f829e90e1884bae1dad4fa5bcd",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 1080,
            "size": 240490,
            "uploadedDate": "2014-07-31T20:00:45.565Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "Screenshot",
            "url": "https://cdn1.epicgames.com/ue/item/store_TappyChicken_screenshot_4-1920x1080-483f24f2a6672156176b16b17e29ae64.png",
            "md5": "483f24f2a6672156176b16b17e29ae64",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 1080,
            "size": 56107,
            "uploadedDate": "2014-07-31T20:00:55.678Z"
          }
        ],
        "thumbnail": "https://cdn1.epicgames.com/ue/item/store_TappyChicken_thumbnail-140x140-5f29f37cd10f728c6aaef67b811f2085.png",
        "learnThumbnail": "https://cdn1.epicgames.com/ue/item/store_TappyChicken_featured-476x246-0ff729b32eac8911749b350a02c26178.png",
        "bundle": false,
        "owned": true,
        "downloadable": true,
        "isCatalogItem": true,
        "commentRatingId": "c1889d04a19f42cd86341de462bdd64b",
        "id": "6af75ba1005e41d0bdacd277f6acf3a2",
        "ratingId": "6af75ba1005e41d0bdacd277f6acf3a2",
        "rating": {
          "targetId": "6af75ba1005e41d0bdacd277f6acf3a2",
          "averageRating": 0,
          "rating5": 0,
          "rating4": 0,
          "rating3": 0,
          "rating2": 0,
          "rating1": 0,
          "legacyRatingNum": 2,
          "rating5Percent": 0,
          "rating4Percent": 0,
          "rating3Percent": 0,
          "rating2Percent": 0,
          "rating1Percent": 0,
          "total": 0
        },
        "reviewed": false
      }
    ]
  }
}



JSON file in folder data:

have you checked if the https server works at all? If you get an HTTP 403 even for ULRs that should be public and can be accessed in a web browser that the server performs TLS fingerprinting, detects your client as Python runtime and denies access because Python is often used for scrapers.

Hi Robert, As I wrote above, if I create the link manually and place it in any browser, I get the response I expect.
For the attached example:
https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/api/assets/asset/6af75ba1005e41d0bdacd277f6acf3a2

Then you are blocked because you use Python.

is there a (legal) way to bless the call that it is not python?

The easiest way is to use an HTTPS intercepting proxy that doesn't base on Python (effectively use a different TLS implementation). Alternatively you can try to fake the TLS fingerprint by changing e.g. the enabled cipher modes and TLS versions, optional TLS fields in CLIENT_HELLO, ... Not sure if Python/requests allows you to change all of them.

Seems that I need a Proxy or whatever, the site blocks my request. :(
